# HTTP request from Embeds Trackable

Tags: user-tracking, iframe

I'm pretty new here so please be gentle with me, a security newb.

I have a website where I want to have a user fill out a form. This form already exists on another website I own (that has greater capabilities), but due to the name of the website/url it could be a physical security risk to the users of the first site (the countries in which the users reside could persecute them for going to the website).

By embedding anything from the 2nd site into my 1st site, am I putting my users at risk? Could the HTTP requests made through the web form on the embed be traced? How is any request through an embed handled? Is it as if the user were going to that website anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply embed content from site A (dangerous) into site B (innocent) somebody watching the traffic of the user will see requests made to site A, i.e. not what you want.

Instead you need to replicate the full site A into site B so that site B only embeds resources from site B and also the final form submission has to submit data to site B. This can be done by making your server at site B a proxy which internally forwards (not redirects!) every request to site A. Be sure to use no fully qualified links which include the name of site A though  but only site-relative or site-absolute links (i.e. links without explicit domain).

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have all the capabilities of site A on site B (made with different CMS systems. site A - WP site B Liferay). So I wouldn't be able to make it fully on site B, but thank you for your answer and a solution that may help others in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Create another unrelated domain with an innocent name (innocent.io), use HTTPS, and send the security-sensitive users there.

Redirect the answers from innocent.io to sensitive.io using server-side connections, not client-side. This will shield your users from inspection, as they will only interact with innocent.io, and only your servers will talk to each other.